# an internal error occurred during: "Generating NED Documentation..."

Tags: documentation, omnet++, veins

When I tried to generate the Veins NED documentation. I got this error
"an internal error occurred during: "Generating NED Documentation..."."

> java.lang.RuntimeException: unknown tag code 43, cannot create object
>   to represent it.

Even after I reinstalled omnetpp and veins, still have the same error. How can I fix it?

Comment: By the way, I use omnetpp 5.4.1 and veins4.7.1

Comment: is there a fix for this yet? I'm running into a same problem. 
Edit: The work around as sommer mentioned in his github issue https://github.com/sommer/veins/issues/96

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it never works. I think veins should provide complete documentation for reference.